# jQuery nivoslider - auto play doesn't work(manualAdvance)

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

my slider does not play automatically. If it is good must be manual advance on false to play the slides automatically play slides. Maybe someone knows why he doesn't work with this code. The other functions works fine. I hope someone can help me.

```
 //Default settings
$.fn.nivoSlider.defaults = {
    effect: 'sliceUp',
    slices: 15,
    boxCols: 8,
    boxRows: 4,
    animSpeed: 500,
    pauseTime: 3000,
    startSlide: 0,
    directionNav: true,
    controlNav: true,
    controlNavThumbs: false,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    manualAdvance: false,
    prevText: 'Prev',
    nextText: 'Next',
    randomStart: false,
    beforeChange: function(){},
    afterChange: function(){},
    slideshowEnd: function(){},
    lastSlide: function(){},
    afterLoad: function(){}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to `main.js`, locate the main slider class, open with your popular editor, 
reduce the `pausetime` to about 5000, add `manualavance: false`, then save.

If your Nivo main slider is not in `main.js`, locate the custom slider folder, click till you get to `home.js`, change `manualadvance` to `false`, reduce your `pausetime` to about 5000.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    // Your settings here
    manualAdvance:false
});
```